# TestCafe how to run runner.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I try to run Testcafe runner.js file, but don't know how to run it.  I know how to write a test and run it locally from the command line. I read the entire documentation in the testcafe and did not understand how to start the runner. Tried the command
`node runner.js`, but I get an error  `Error: Cannot find module '~/OtherTestcafeV2/runner.js'`.
I read about runner here https://testcafe.io/documentation/402641/reference/testcafe-api/runner  and https://testcafe.io/documentation/402640/reference/testcafe-api/testcafe but didn't understand what to do and how to launch it.
Please explain in detail. [that is my project GitHub link](https://github.com/HamoNazaryan/testcafeSimpleExample)

Comment: The way you run the TestCafe runner is correct. Your error is not related to TestCafe but to your folder structure. Please share your full project to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I edit my question and add a link to my Github repository. Where you can see my full project.

Comment: The project is incomplete. There are missing code files with `allure-reporter` and `reporter-config`. I commented out the code lines that require the missing parts. Then I ran the runner with the `node runner.js` command from the project folder. TestCafe runs successfully.

Comment: Hi @Alex, can you provide me your code, I commented reporter code line too and try to run it, but I get the same error.``` /home/user/Desktop/otherTestcafe/runner.js:35
createTestCafe()
^

ReferenceError: createTestCafe is not defined```   Node version 17.0.1

Comment: take a look at: https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/bf35fbd89b0847965892e8ceb9abab20

Comment: ok thanks, all works !